# How to search specific text in 104GB file with only one line?

Tags: linux, search, grep

I just finished calculating 111 billion digits of the PI number using y-cruncher, and there 104GB file.

I ran into a problem.

I want to play around, try to search there for name, values, titles and so on, that is a certain sequence of digits.
However, search things like grep fgrep and others simply crash, even for lack of memory.

The whole number is in a txt file on a single line.

So, how do I find the text there once now, no matter how long it takes, preferably without splitting it into small files or anything like that, so that the file stays the same.

And how in the future to search there very quickly, for example to make a site for search and already there to use sql / partitioning into files, or something else, suggest here something that could help.

thanks in advance, i tried how i said grep, fgrepX, and some other opensource stuffs.

Comment: Please use the internationally agreed SI units. Gigabyte is "GB". Gigabit is "Gb". The prefix "g" is not specified.

Comment: Ready, i think correct now, 104GB, so 104 Gigabytes

Comment: Yes, “out of memory”

Comment: I thunk cuz i have all digits in one line

Comment: Can you give an example of the command you run ?

Comment: The problem may be because `grep` considers your file as text, not binary. If you want to know if substring is present without knowing it's offset, you can force binary mode with `-U`.

Comment: @dimich what makes you think the file isn't text?

Comment: @EdMorton As i know, grep tries to detect if file is text or binary by searching for bytes `0` or >`0x7F`. If file is recognized as text, grep tries to read it line by line. In OP case the file contain digits only, but such "line" is too long. I tested grep forcing it to treat big file as text with memory limited by `ulimit`, and indeed it fails.

Comment: @dimich A file of digits ending with a newline is a text file per the POSIX standard and most text processing tools would treat is a text file even if the newline was missing. I don't see anything in the question to suggest that's not what the OP has but I've no idea what `y-cruncher` is and I may be missing something.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm just speculating why grep fails to process big file in some cases but doesn't fail in others. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/what-makes-grep-consider-a-file-to-be-binary). However `grep` sources are open.

Answer (score 4):

`grep` reads the whole file into memory before searching for the text in it. You could instead use GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT and tell it to search `1000` or whatever number you like of chars at a time:

```
gawk -v RS='.{0,1000}' 'RT ~ /regexp/' file
```

but then you need to consider the matching string could be broken across that 1000 char boundary so make sure each record is large enough to hold the matching string and that you test 2 records concatenated each time, e.g.:

```
gawk -v RS='.{0,1000}' '(prev RT) ~ /regexp/; {prev=RT}' file
```

The above is obviously untested as there no sample input/output in the question for us to test with, and the OP didn't tell us what they wanted to output if/when the regexp matches, etc. so that's all left for them to figure out too but maybe something like this that just prints `found` or `not found` along with the appropriate exit status is all that's needed:

```
$ echo '00007770000' | gawk -v RS='.{0,3}' '(prev RT) ~ /777/{f=1; exit} {prev=RT} END{print (f ? "" : "not ") "found"; exit !f}'
found
$ echo $?
0
```

```
$ echo '00007770000' | gawk -v RS='.{0,3}' '(prev RT) ~ /333/{f=1; exit} {prev=RT} END{print (f ? "" : "not ") "found"; exit !f}'
not found
$ echo $?
1
```

As [@dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) suggested in a comment, given that the OPs input doesn't contain spaces (otherwise `dd` would strip them from the end of each block it outputs), the following would work using POSIX tools:

```
dd cbs=1000 conv=unblock if=file | awk '(prev $0) ~ /regexp/; {prev=$0}'
```

and, now I think about it, this would also work with POSIX tools whether spaces were present or not:

```
fold -b -w 1000 file | awk '(prev $0) ~ /regexp/; {prev=$0}'
```

Technically the input to `fold` should end in a newline or it's undefined behavior per POSIX, but it'll probably work and if the input doesn't end in a newline and the version of `fold` on your box requires one you can always add it:

```
{ cat file; printf '\n'; } | fold -b -w 1000 | awk '(prev $0) ~ /regexp/; {prev=$0}'
```

I'm using the `-b` argument to `fold` so it's input line length isn't restricted to [LINE_MAX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/limits.h.html) but then we're dealing with bytes rather than characters which may behave undesirably if your input includes multi-byte characters.

Comment: A POSIX way could be `dd cbs=1000 conv=unblock | awk '{prev $0)~/regexp/; {prev=$0}'`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yup, as long as the input doesn't contain spaces, as in the OPs case, that should work fine. I added that to my answer, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If standard programs aren't good enough, try programs that are meant for searching binary files.

Your file is not really binary, and some of these programs might expect you to for example write the needle in hexadecimal, but at least they won't try to read the input line by line.

This article https://www.baeldung.com/linux/binary-files-pattern-search mentions these tools:

- bgrep - https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep or this fork: https://github.com/rsharo/bgrep
- bbe - https://bbe-.sourceforge.net/
- GHex (GUI) (but "GHex loads the entire file to memory")
- Bless (GUI) - https://github.com/afrantzis/bless

Some Linux distributions have some packages for some of these tools.

Answer (score 1):

A Perl one-liner for doing that:

```
perl -MSys::Mmap -E'mmap($data,0,PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED,STDIN);while(($ix=index$data,$ARGV[0],($ix//-1)+1)>=0){say"match at $ix"}' word </long/file/path
```

It needs the Perl module [Sys::Mmap](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::Mmap) installed. In Debian (and its derivatives) it is available as package `libsys-mmap-perl`.

`Sys::Mmap` allows one to wrap the contents of a file as a Perl scalar. Under the hood it uses [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). But the usage of those scalars is tricky because some perl builtins may try to duplicate them resulting in an out of memory errors.

For instance, I have been unable to run regular expressions over the scalars created by `Sys::Mmap` without triggering a copy of it. On the other hand, `index`, used in the one-liner, works!

Answer (score 0):

If standard programs aren't good enough, make your own.

I wrote this one for you in Rust. I chose Rust because it has an impressive [memchr::memmem library](https://docs.rs/memchr/latest/memchr/index.html). It should be reasonably fast. It definitely won't run out of memory. I hope it doesn't have any bugs. Search online for how to install Rust. Compile the program with `cargo build --release`.

fastgrep/src/main.rs:

```rust
use std::io::Read;
use std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    const BUF_SIZE: usize = 8192;

    let args: Vec<_> = std::env::args_os().collect();
    let needle: &[u8] = args[1].as_bytes();
    let filename = &args[2];

    let finder = memchr::memmem::Finder::new(needle);
    let mut file = std::fs::File::open(filename)?;
    let mut offset = 0;
    let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = vec!();

    loop {
        let old_len = buffer.len();
        buffer.resize(old_len + BUF_SIZE, 0);
        let bytes_read = file.read(&mut buffer[old_len..])?;
        buffer.truncate(old_len + bytes_read);
        // eprintln!("old_len {old_len} bytes_read {bytes_read}");

        for offset_in_buffer in finder.find_iter(&buffer) {
            println!("{}", offset + offset_in_buffer);
        }

        if bytes_read == 0 {
            break;
        }

        let advance = buffer.len().saturating_sub(needle.len() - 1);
        // eprintln!("advance {advance}");
        offset += advance;
        buffer = buffer[advance..].to_vec();
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

fastgrep/Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "fastgrep"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
memchr = "2.6.4"
```

Rust playground example (hardcoded arguments): 
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=e2385dbb56bdaee15ba4b827245a19e9

Good luck! Please write a comment to tell me if it works!